# WARNING: Logcat was not cleared on the device itself because of a bug in Android 8.0 (Oreo)

Tags: android

Recently started Android development. Instead of using an emulator, I run my apps on my smartphone (Samsung A5 2017 SM -A520F) which has Android 8.0 Oreo installed. I also use Android Studio version 2021.3.1 with the latest Logcat version.

I am concerned about the message that appears in the Logcat output after I click on "Clear Logcat"

Message:
WARNING: Logcat was not cleared on the device itself because of a bug in Android 8.0 (Oreo)

[Logcat Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POtVD.png)

Is there anything I can do to resolve this issue or even prevent my device from filling up with garbage logs?

Comment: I have the same problem with my test device Motorola Z Style with Android 8. The best  temporary solution is reboot the device...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to restart **adb** ( *Android Debug Bridge* ) !

1. Open terminal panel (Win: `Alt+F12` , Mac: `fn + option + F12`)
2. Terminate the **adb** server process :

   ```
   adb kill-server
   ```
3. Restart adb server :

   ```
   adb start-server
   ```